# Laravel refresh page takes up to 4s to load the whole DOM

Tags: laravel, npm, composer-php, package-managers

I'm new with Laravel's framework, so correct me if i'm mistaken.

I have set up some templates with some assets (css and js) in its corresponding folder:

SASS and JS goes inside `resources/sass` and `resources/js` respectively, which then gets compiled into `public/css` and `public/js`

Views go into `resources/views`, and then i have set up some routes inside `routes/web.php`
If you want me to add some more information i can for sure add it.

[Image of console network debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yp7Sk.png)

Please, ignore images time load as I dont care the loading of them cause they load after DOM.
What I'm asking here is: why is every .css file or .js file taking more than a second to load?

Comment: Are these delays while testing on localhost? Or on a remote server?

Comment: It's in localhost, gonna try uploading them to a host and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Seems to load fine in a host, maybe it has something to do with compiling? Load time was 1.09s

Comment: Please share more details. How are high loading times of such ressources connected to [tag:composer-php] or [tag:package-managers]?

Comment: could you explain what you are asking a bit more concise? I don't know if this is what you asking for, but the way i get the url of assets is: {{ asset(css/[file].css) }}

Comment: As you haven't shared what **exactly** causes the loading times, it's close to impossible to provide help. And as such loading times are usually not connected to package managers, I've asked for clarification about this

Comment: As I stated before, I have literally no idea of how Laravel works, neither even tried to work with a framework before. Everything looks to be set up just fine as when provided by a web host connection, load times decreases to less than 1s.

It seems like it has something to do with my **localhost**. Do you have any idea why this could be possibly happening?

PS: I'm accessing through `php artisan serve` which then generates a **127.0.0.1:port**

+PS: When accessing a localhost file (like a xampp htdocs project) load times are just fine so it has to be something wrong with laravel or comp

Comment: I'm wondering if it has something to do with Laravel compiling in real time the assets folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution found**

Seems like xDebug was causing strong loads in my page, commenting it fixed it.